# HP Fortify View Issues Created Since Last Scan

Tags: fortify

All!

I am currently running HP Fortifify SSC. Is there any way to view the issues which were changed between two scans?

In other words.

```
Scan A = 10 Issues
Scan B = 12 Issues
```

I want to view the 2 new issues between scans A and B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're looking at the issues either in Audit Workbench or Software Security Center, you'll see a drop down box called "Group By". There's an option there for "New Issue'. That will show you the issues based on when they were identified.

Comment: I am running version 4.00.0096. I see No Grouping, Fortify Priority Order, Analysis Type, Folder, & Correlated, but no New.

Comment: Are you using Audit Workbench, an IDE plugin, or SSC to view the results? That is a really old version of Fortify, but there should be an option that says "New Issue". That capability has been around since almost the beginning.

Comment: SSC. I'll see about getting an upgrade.

Comment: That's the version of SSC. SCA is version 6.00.0096.

Comment: I got it! I was looking at the overview, but needed to look at the audit issues view.